# how to render partial and a variable on same page using jbuilder gem

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I am using Rails 4, ruby 2, and jbuilder gem to respond json.

I have a file `index.json.jbuilder`
in which following code is written

```
json.partial! "apis/contents", comments: @comments
json.name @name
```

Returning following error :-

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be due to the collection of objects, you can define partial explicitly, like this:

```
json.partial! partial: 'apis/contents', collection: @comments, as: :comment
```

Comment: I want to append `json.name @name` into the partial's response. How do I do that ?

Comment: This does not seem to address the problem. Any other suggestions?